# Using directories in npm and pointing them to src?

Tags: node.js, npm, import, module, package

I've created a package that has different directories, and I import them this way:

```
import module1 from 'mypackage/module1'
import module2 from 'mypackage/module2'
...
```

The problem with this is that all the code is on the root of the package:

```
module1/
module2/
.gitignore
package.json
```

I'd like this structure:

```
src/
  module1/
  module2/
.gitignore
package.json
```

Is it possible to put these modules in src/ and still load them as the example above? Any property in package.json that allow it?

Answer (score 0):

`./src/module1` should be moved to `.` package root, which is a a common way to do this. This is not a problem since `./src` is usually expected to be built to `./dist`; it can be built to `.` instead or moved from `./dist` before the package is published, e.g. with `prepublish` hook.

Another way to do this is to re-export modules, e.g.:

*./module1.js*

```
export * from './src/module1';
```

This is not a good solution for NPM module because `./module1` is ES module, while NPM packages are expected to contain CommonJS modules for compatibility as well. It's acceptable only for private packages that are supposed to be consumed only as ES modules.